# infinite homotopy classes of maps between finite simplicial complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250023) proves that there are at most countably many homotopy classes of maps $|K| → |L|$ for finite simplicial complexes $K$ and $L$.

Can you give an example that there are countably **infinite** many homotopy classes of maps $|K| → |L|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K=L=S^1$ (triangulated however you like) with the infinitely many homotopy classes
$$f_n(z)=z^n
$$

Comment: Yes. Because $π_1(S^1) =\Bbb Z$.